# How can I generate enemies in random time (same position) in Unity 3D using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I generate repeatedly enemies each `1.75f`. But I don't know how can I use a Random function. My prototype game is like the game in Chrome Browser,It appears  when the page is not found.

Thank you for helping me.

Here is my code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class EnemyGeneratorController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject enemyPrefeb;
        public float generatorTimer = 1.75f;

        void Start () 
        {

    }

    void Update ()
    {

    }

    void CreateEnemy()
    {
        Instantiate (enemyPrefeb, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public void StartGenerator()
    {
        InvokeRepeating ("CreateEnemy", 0f, generatorTimer);
    }

    public void CancelGenerator(bool clean = false)
    {
        CancelInvoke ("CreateEnemy");
        if (clean)
        {
            Object[] allEnemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Enemy");
            foreach (GameObject enemy in allEnemies)
            {
                Destroy(enemy);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to generate the random enemies?

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to instantiate the same enemy at a random position every 1.75 seconds?

Comment: Do not use InvokeRepeating, its very bad practice (try StartCoroutine or update time checking instead)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the comments. I want to generate random time, not position.

Comment: @federiandco, time randomization was added, is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 6):

You can use StartCoroutine for simple enemy instantiating:

```
using System.Collections;
```

...

```
private IEnumerator EnemyGenerator()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Vector3 randPosition = transform.position + (Vector3.up * Random.value); //Example of randomizing
        Instantiate (enemyPrefeb, randPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(generatorTimer);
    }
}

public void StartGenerator()
{
    StartCoroutine(EnemyGenerator());
}

public void StopGenerator()
{
    StopAllCoroutines();
}
```

And, as Andrew Meservy said, if you wanna add the randomness to the timer (for example to make spawn delay random from 0.5 sec to 2.0 sec) then you can just replace yield return to this one:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(Mathf.Lerp(0.5f, 2.0f, Random.value));
```

Comment: Since OP wants a random time, just replace generatorTimer with Random.value and you have the answer I think.

Answer (score 1):

Modified version to generate the enemies

Use StartCoroutine with Random Time

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class EnemyGeneratorController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject enemyPrefeb;
         public float generatorTimer { set; get; }

        void Start () 
        {
```

generatorTimer = 1.75f;

```
    }

    void Update ()
    {

    }

    void IEnumerator CreateEnemy()
    {
        Instantiate (enemyPrefeb, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(generatorTimer);
        generatorTimer = Random.Range(1f, 5f);
    }

    public void StartGenerator()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CreateEnemy());

    }

    public void CancelGenerator(bool clean = false)
    {
        CancelInvoke ("CreateEnemy");
        if (clean)
        {
            Object[] allEnemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Enemy");
            foreach (GameObject enemy in allEnemies)
            {
                Destroy(enemy);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```